# EventToCommand never works for me

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm attempting to change my current code and move it towards an MVVM design.

I have a grid control as such:

```
        <ctl:GridContainer x:Name="GridResponses" CellValueChanged="GridResponses_CellValueChanged">
            .
            .
            .
        </ctl:GridContainer>
```

with an even as such:

```
        Private Sub GridResponses_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As CellValueEventArgs)
            If e.Column.FieldName = "PRIORITY" Then
               .
               .
               .
            End If
        End Sub
```

now I'm moving the above code to using MVVM Light and doing the following:

```
        <ctl:GridContainer DataContext="{Binding ResponsesDataView}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellValueChanged">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding GridCellValueChangedCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ctl:GridContainer>
```

and in my ViewModel I have the following RelayCommand declared as follows:

```
        Private m_cmdGridCellValueChanged As RelayCommand(Of CellValueEventArgs)

        .
        .
        .

        m_cmdGridCellValueChanged = New RelayCommand(Of CellValueEventArgs) _
                (Sub(e)
                     If e.Column.FieldName = "PRIORITY" Then
                         .
                         .
                         .
                     End If
                 End Sub)
```

and it NEVER executes! I even tried using a parameter-less RelayCommand and tried showing a MessageBox and that didn't event work.

Is the EventToCommand limited in terms of specific events? Am I doing something wrong???

Comment: What's a GridContainer?

Comment: My own usercontrol that contains a DevExpress DXGrid within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is in binding. You are searching for command in `ResponsesDataView`. you need to traverse up for your View's DataContext -

```
 <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.GridCellValueChangedCommand, 
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                         AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

Comment: Ohhh, I didn't even think of that! OK I'll make my change and report back, I really hope it solves the problem :)

Comment: Check your `Output` window. If your command name is there then your binding doesn't get resolved. Simple as that..!!